# Where to see a Ping Pong show in Thailand?

Tags: thailand

As I searched, there are shows in Pattaya, Patong, Bangkok, I wonder where I should see a show. By the way, what are the general rules revolving around attending a ping pong show? How many bahts should we bring per person?

Comment: are you sure it's illegal?

Comment: @NateEldredge What makes you think it's illegal?

Comment: @NateEldredge - ping pong shows are simply nude shows, no prostitution involved.

Comment: Under Thai law, ping pong shows are officially prohibited under obscenity legislation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_pong_show

Answer (score 3):

In Bangkok, the area to find ping pong shows is Patpong. Granted, it's been a while since I was there, so things might have changed, but when you're getting close, there's no escaping the touts trying to force you in.

Before you enter, extremely clearly agree what you're paying to whom and what you get for it in return. Typically, don't pay the tout, pay on entry to, probably, a madam.

Pay any drinks you get as you order them, when you get them. Don't build up a tab.

Be extremely wary of buying drinks for the girls. If you must, be clear as to how much the drinks will cost you.

[Here](http://babakfakhamzadeh.com/article/ping-pong-at-pat-pong) is a writeup of my experience in 2007.

Comment: Also, when you're in Bangkok at khao san road, people will offer you deals to take their tuktuk/cab to a show. If you are there, there are a bunch of cabs waiting to take you back.

Comment: The only rule for staying solvent and alive in Thailand is, don't ever let anyone "take" you anywhere.  Decide where you want to go, and figure out how to get there, because if someone buttonholes you on the street with any sort of proposition, it's dinars-to-kip that go along with him and you'll find yourself badly clipped or worse.